# Sum 50% more in the value of the property when click

Tags: jquery, sum, zooming

I'd like to make the `zoom in` button to sum 50% more to the value always when clicked. In this code, I want to manipulate the Zoom property into the `#mapBox`

This the HTML where there are buttons to zoom In and Out

```
<img src="images/zoomIn.jpg" alt="Zoom In" id="zoomInButton" /> //Zoom In
<img src="images/zoomOut.jpg" alt="Zoom Out" id="zoomOutButton" /> //Zoom Out
<div id="mapBox"> //add zoom style here
  <img src="images/map.svg" alt="Map" />
</div>
```

And the jQuery where I add the `zoom` style to the div `#mapBox`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zoomInButton").click(function() {
    $("#mapBox").css({
        "zoom" : "150%"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So what is the question? You provided some code with no mention of what it is or isn't doing

Comment: @charlietfl the code is set to add the zoom property inside the `#mapBox` div! That works, however it is only set to add the value of 150%! I'd like to add more 50% every time when it is clicked, so 100% to 150% and them 150% to 200% and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty quick and dirty example, but should give you an idea of one way to start. This creates functions to zoom in and out, and binds them to your buttons.

```
//starting zoom amount 
var zoom = 150;

function zoomIn(){
  zoom = zoom + 50;
  $("#mapBox").css({
    "zoom" : zoom + "%"
  });
}

function zoomOut(){
  zoom = zoom - 50;
  $("#mapBox").css({
    "zoom" : zoom + "%"
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zoomInButton").on('click', zoomIn);
  $("#zoomOutButton").on('click', zoomOut);
  $("#mapBox").css({
    "zoom" : zoom + "%"
  });
});
```